# Error accessing wcf service asynchronously using BeginExecute in c# .net

Tags: c#, xamarin, wcf-data-services

I am building an standard odata client using:
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.Portable
Windows 8
VS2013

I have added a service reference to the project (TMALiveData) with authorisation.  Now I want to retrieve data.  I am using the following code, but when I do, I get a null pointer reference in the final loop.

The code is:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Services.Client;

namespace testLSconWithMSv2
{
   public class testLSCon
    {
        static string mResult;

        public static string result { get { return mResult; } }

        public static void testREADLiveConnection()
        {

            Uri tmaLiveDataRoot = new Uri("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/xxx.svc/");
            TMLiveData.TMALiveData mLiveData = new TMLiveData.TMALiveData(tmaLiveDataRoot);
            mResult = null;


            DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType> query = (DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType>)mLiveData.JobTypes.Where(c => c.IsActive == true);
            mResult = "Trying to READ the data";
            try
            {
                query.BeginExecute(OnQueryComplete, query);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mResult = "Error on beginExecute: " + ex.Message;
            }


        }

        private static  void OnQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
        {

            DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType> query = result as DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType>;
            mResult = "Done!";
            try
            {
                foreach (TMLiveData.JobType jobType in query.EndExecute(result))
                {
                    mResult += jobType.JobType1 + ",";
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mResult = "Error looping for items: " + ex.Message;
            }



        }

    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? 
I have based the approach on the ms example at: [How to Execute Async...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756367(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Which object is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException` because you're trying to cast the `IAsyncResult` to a `DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType>`. You need to cast the [`IAsyncResult.AsyncState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncstate(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
private static  void OnQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
        DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType> query = (DataServiceQuery<TMLiveData.JobType>) result.AsyncState;

        mResult = "Done!";
        try
        {
            foreach (TMLiveData.JobType jobType in query.EndExecute(result))
            {
                mResult += jobType.JobType1 + ",";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mResult = "Error looping for items: " + ex.Message;
        }
}
```

On a side note, i used an explicit cast here instead of the `as` operator. If you did, you would get an `InvalidCastException` instead of a `NullReferenceException`, which would be make it a whole lot easier for you to discover the error.

Comment: Yes, i find it good practice if using a try cast to always follow up with a null check. If you never expact a null tben cast directly...

Comment: It is not about "expecting null" IMO. it is about you being 100 percent certain of the type you're supposed to be working with. If it *might* be it, then use `as`.

Comment: thanks for your help.  It still fails, but for another reason:   StatusCode System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.  I'll have to work out how to add credentials to the request - I'll make another question.